# GitLab CI with multiple repository dependencies

Tags: django, gitlab, gitlab-ci

With my Django setup I have the main project as a repo and then for each Django app that lives in the project another repo. This is so that each app has its own repository on something like GitLab for example.

When doing a GitLab CI config script it automatically pulls in the code from the main repo as this is where the gitlab-ci script is located. Other than faffing with SSH keys and manually cloning by URL in the CI descriptor, is there any other  way to tell GitLab to automatically pull in all the apps from there respective git URL to run the tests on?

Example project structure.

```
djangoproject
  djangoapp1
    .git => http://gitlab.com/user/djangoapp1
  djangoapp2
    .git => http://gitlab.com/user/djangoapp2
  djangoapp3
    .git => http://gitlab.com/user/djangoapp3
  ...
  other django files
  ...
  .git http://gitlab.com/user/djangoproject
```

Comment: Maybe git submodules are something you might want to consider? A simple `git pull --recurse-submodules` will get all submodules and then you can run your test on. Other than that CI wasn't really designed for this particular scenario.

Comment: I thought using submodules is limited to one git submodule per git repo.

Comment: You can have multiple submodules. I have seen projects with two or three and I don't think there really is a upper limit.

Comment: Thanks. I was experimenting with submodules but it is probably SourceTree bugging out. Tried it via the command line and other tools and submodules does indeed work with more than one. Up-voted your comment.